# Change HashSet prototype C#

Tags: c#, hashset

Can I change the prototype of a HashSet? What I want to achieve is that when HashSet is created to add a property `count` which will be updated during each `.Add()` and also `.Remove()` operations. I think it will be better than iterating over the collection. I would like to do it also for SortedHash and Dictionary and SortedDictionary (u get the point).

EDIT: By prototype what I mean is like in javascript where I can say `Array.prototype` for example. I hope it's the same with C#.

Comment: All those classes have already a `Count` property

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking about the attempted or assumed solution instead of the actual problem. What is the *actual* problem and why do you think you need to change a prototype to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't change the prototype in C# because C# is not a prototypical language. However, `HashSet<T>` *already has* a `.Count` property. If you so wish, you could use extension methods to add extra methods. Extension properties may come in a not-too-distant language update. Or: subclass and add properties in the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to because all those Collection already have a `Count` property which does exactly what you want.

About "changing the prototype": No. There is no such thing in C#. The closest would be an Extension Method.

Let's say you would want to add a method to HashSet that returns the count:

```
static class HashSetExtensions // needs to be static
{
   public static int GetCount( this HashSet set ) // notice the 'this' which indicates an extension method
   {
      int count = set.Count; // you can access the public interface of the type in your extension method
      return count;
   }
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
var myHashSet = new HashSet<int>();
var count = myHashSet.GetCount(); // GetCount is the extension method and you call it just like you call a normal method.
```